# Implementing gravity to bouncing ball JAVA

Tags: java, gravity, bounce

this is where im currently at

```
private void move () {
        if (x + angleX < 0) {
            angleX = vx;
        } else if (  + angleX > getWidth() - 50) {
           angleX = -vx;
        } else if (y + angleY < 0) {
            angleY = vy;
        } else if (y + angleY > getHeight() - 50) {
            angleY = -vy;
        }

        x = x + angleX;
        y = y + angleY;
    }
```

I would like to implement gravity with this formula

x = x + t*vx;

y = y + t*vy - G*(t*t/2.0);

where gravity is 10.

Currently it just moves the ball up and down.

Any help is appreciated.

Whole source:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class App extends JPanel {

    int x = 165, y = 0;
    int angleX = 1, angleY = 1;
    int G = 10;
    int vx = 5;
    int vy = 1;

    private void move () {
        if (x + angleX < 0) {
            angleX = vx;
        } else if (  + angleX > getWidth() - 50) {
           angleX = -vx;
        } else if (y + angleY < 0) {
            angleY = vy;
        } else if (y + angleY > getHeight() - 50) {
            angleY = -vy;
        }

        x = x + angleX;
        y = y + angleY;
    }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50); // 50x50 boll
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Studsande boll");
        App app = new App();
        frame.add(app);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            app.move();
            app.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```